# When a river updates data in elastic search, is missing data deleted?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am using the JDBC river to populate docs in elastic search from Sql Server. I am fetching data using a simple Sql query and  have set the polling to 20 mins. Now suppose the river fetches 100 docs the first time it polls sql server. And after 20 mins, when it fetches the data again it gets 120 docs where there are 40 new records and 20 records which were deleted in sql server are not there.

Will the records which were deleted from the Sql server also be deleted from the index at ElasticSearch? (This doesnt seem to be happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After observing the behavior overnight I find that the index has the correct records and deleted records are not present anymore. Strangely, this did not happen when I restarted the elastics search service. Anyway, does answer my question.